# Configure the LootLocker SDK for unity webgl build to itch.io?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development, unity-webgl

What am I supposed to do here? I am at this point https://docs.lootlocker.com/getting-started/unity-tutorials/getting-started-with-unity/configure-the-sdk and I have no idea what to do.

I want to configure it to do a webgl game for game jam game on itch.io.

**Can anybody help in setting up this for webgl itch.io game?**

In linked in this question page these options are explained but I'm not understand what that means and what I should put here for web itch.io game.

I also started topic on ask unity: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1919598/configure-the-lootlocker-sdk-for-unity-webgl-build.html

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LootLocker employee here!
You do not need to do anything more after this step, the SDK is configured and you are good to go :). The platforms settings are only used if you target these specific platforms.
So you are now ready to start using LootLocker :)